# How can I map array of strings in my select component?

Tags: reactjs, select

I've got a select component built on select tag. I have an object of data:

```
 const options= [
    { initialValue: "abc", data: ["data5", "data55", "data555"] },
    { initialValue: "zxy", data: ["data2", "data22", "data222"] },
  ];
```

Here I am getting 2 dropdown components with initial value but I am not getting data after initialValue.

So basically in my select I need abc, data5, data55, data555 and zxy, data, data2, data22, data222
But I am getting abc, data5data55data555 and zxy, datadata2data222

```
  {options.map((val, index) => {
        return (
          <Select>
            <option value="" key={index}>
              {val.initialValue}
            </option>

              <option value={`${val}`} key={index + 1}>
                {val.data}
              </option>;
          </Select>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: So you want, for example, 4 options from `{ initialValue: "abc", data: ["data5", "data55", "data555"] }`, being "abc", "data5", "data55", and "data555"?

Comment: yeap exactly and I have done the below solution which did work for me that's why I asked here

Comment: Great. Provided answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate data values also using the map.

```
const options = [{
        initialValue: "abc",
        data: ["data5", "data55", "data555"]
    },
    {
        initialValue: "zxy",
        data: ["data2", "data22", "data222"]
    },
];

{options.map((val, index) => {
        return (
          <Select>
            <option value="" key={index}>
              {val.initialValue}
            </option>
            {
                val.data.map((d, i) => (<option value={`${d}`} key={`${index}-${i}`}>{d}</option>))
            }
          </Select>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: this solution works, my problem was with key attribute

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the `val.data` by `Array.map()` to add several `<option>`.

```js
{options.map((val, index) => {
  return (
    <Select>
      <option value="" key={index}>
        {val.initialValue}
      </option>
      
      {val.data.map((d, j) => (
        <option value={`${d}`} key={`options${index}-${j}`>
          {d}
        </option>
      )}
    </Select>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` two times.

```js
{
  options.map((item, index) => (
    <select key={index}>
      <option value={item.initialValue}>{item.initialValue}</option>
      {item.data.map((value, index) => (
        <option value={value} key={index}>
          {value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flattening your options first, then mapping the options using a single array and key set. It still "double maps" like several of the other answers here but does so in a more functional programming way, i.e. the second mapping isn't nested. It's a bit more **DRY** and (subjectively) easier to read IMO.

[array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Map each set of options to a single array (i.e. `initialValue` and `data` spread into it) value which is then overall flattened down to a single array of *all* the option values.

```
<select>
  {options
    .flatMap(({ initialValue, data }) => [initialValue, ...data])
    .map((option, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={option}>
        {option}
      </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-map-array-of-strings-in-my-select-component]

Comment: why do you suggest that?

Comment: @Sonny49 Ah, basically just answered that just before you commented. It's more **DRY** as there is only a single function now creating `option` tags. I also believe it is easier to read since the logic flow has now been flattened, no nesting to read *into*.